# white text on Colored Background in BIDs (color set with expression)

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using white text on a coloured background, and the background is set using a variable.

[image: Setting background color]

When using a variable (or any expression) for BackgroundColor the background (while developing) is white, which means white text cant be seen.

How can I see the text while developing reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've set the background color using an expression, and want the text to be white, but need to be able to see the text while developing your report...

simply set the font using an expression also.  in the case above

```
="White"
```

That will allow you to see text entered (which just turns the text back to black in dev mode)